# Project Euler #14 Optimizing Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on Project Euler Problem #14, and it seems like my algorithm is running extremely slowly. I'm trying to generate the next Collatz number, starting from 2, and replacing a MAX value for the length every time I encounter a larger length. I can't seem to think of a better way to approach the problem, and how to implement it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please add code, an explanation of exactly what "Problem #14" is, and maybe a link to it.

Comment: perhaps more suited to code review?

Comment: This will likely be closed.  StackOverflow likes questions in which you show us your code and tell us what's wrong.   "Improve my algorithm" is unlikely to get much in the way of helpful responses.

Comment: The whole point of project Euler is that naive brute force algorithms won't work, because they are too slow. You are expected to apply (mathematical) knowledge to make a better algorithm. If you don't have that knowledge, SO can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attempting a brute-force approach and recalculate the next Collatz number, it might be useful to **store each pair of number and resulting Collatz value** into some sort of data structure, so that we can check whether we have already encountered a number in our evaluation and add its steps without recalculating the value again.

Through this “memoization" technique, evaluating the sequence from 20 might look something like:

1. Start: `20`
2. Have already evaluated this number (does a pair contain the key 20?): `False`
3. Generate next Collatz number: `10`, and add `1` to the current path length
4. Have already evaluated this number (does a pair contain the key 10?): `True` – the program evaluates from 1, increasing in value each iteration.
5. Get Collatz path length [10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 6 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1]: `7`
6. Add the path length of 10 to the current path length (1), and the total path length is `11`.

An implementation of this algorithm might look like the following:

```
long long nextCollatz(long long x)
{
    if (x % 2 == 0) return x / 2;
    return (3 * x) + 1;
}

long long p014()
{
    //key is the number, value is the end result
    //check if the set contains the number before each call of nextCollatz
    map<long long, int> m;
    map<long long, int>::iterator it = m.begin();

    long long MAX_NUM = -1;
    long long VAL = 0;
    int count;
    for (long long i = 40; i < 1000000; i++){
        count = 0;
        if (m.find(i) == m.end()) //key not found (e.g. haven't generated the ending collatz number)
        {
            long long temp = i;
            while (temp > 1)
            {
                count = count + 1;
                temp = nextCollatz(temp); //next collatz number
                if (m.find(temp) != m.end()) //found the number! we now have the ending position
                {
                    long long val = m[temp]; //with i being the key, get the value (# of iterations needed to get to 1)
                    count += val; //current count + number of values to get to one
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (count > MAX_NUM) {
                MAX_NUM = count; 
                VAL = i;
            }
            m.insert(pair<long long, int>(i, count));
        }
    }
    return VAL;
}
```